# IF function with drop down menu; am I doing something wrong?

Tags: excel, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I got an IF function, which has a logical expression with a drop down menu. I'm a total excel rookie and have just learned how to work with drop down menus. Am I doing anything out of the ordinary here?

Formula: `=IF(G31="Ascending";H31;IF(G31="Descending";H31+I31*5;IF(G31="Pyramid";H31;H31)))`

The given output: #NAAM? (probably #NAME? in english):

[image: Photo]

The text saying Ascending is the drop down menu with three options: Ascending, Descending, Pyramid and Same. The cell with "Ascending" is H31, the cell with "70" is G31 and the cell with "7,5" is I31.

Comment: Can you run through "Evaluate Formula" to determine where in your formula your getting the error? What language version are you using? Would it not have an alternate version of `IF` in your Excel's language?

Comment: I'm guessing that its a Dutch version. Could you try using `ALS` instead of `IF`?

Comment: I set up a worksheet with the values of G31:I31 as shown in the picture. I put the formula in G33 and got a result of 70. The only change that I made was to change the semi-colons `;` to commas `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(G31="Ascending",H31,IF(G31="Descending",H31+I31*5,IF(G31="Pyramid",H31,H31))) **, not ;**
```